# How to stop Facebook like button reloading page

Tags: jquery, facebook

I am using a jquery feed scroll similar to Foursquare's home page.

The script works perfectly until I added facebook like buttons.

Within each feed, I have a Facebook like button. Each time a new feed is scrolled, the page reloads itself. Is there away to make the page stop loading itself with the facebook like button in the feed?

Comment: is't facebook like button is page like button.. how can you put multiple like buttons on the same page?

Comment: @Idlecool, it is used in the case an article is extremely popular

Comment: @Harmen: but can we have multiple like buttons on single page??

Comment: @Idlecool, yes, because it's possible to set the URL to like: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

Comment: you can have multiple facebook like buttons on a single page, with different 'urls to like' for each like buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah! Mike you can have multiple like buttons on same page. Just set URL field of each button to URL of pages you wanted to like one by one. That's it!